# Can we prove how large a closed system can be before it loses consistency?

Tags: logic

I understand that Godel says that a closed system can't be both complete and consistent. But that raises an obvious question, doesn't it?

We may never have a united mathematical theory, but surely we can complete smaller sub-disciplines?

Answer (score 2):

That is *not* what the incompleteness theorem says. Here is a perfectly sensible complete and consistent theory: take [true arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_arithmetic), the set of all true first-order statements about the natural numbers. More precisely I mean the theory whose axioms are all of the true first-order statements of arithmetic.

True arithmetic is not a counterexample to the incompleteness theorem because it is not *computable*. What that means is that there is no program that prints a list of all the theorems of true arithmetic. This is related to [Tarski's undefinability theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem). Godel's incompleteness theorem only applies to computable theories, and computable theories are the only ones we care about in this context, because if a theory isn't computable then there's no way to tell what constitutes a valid proof starting from its axioms. (In true arithmetic, the "proof" of any theorem simply consists of the statement of that theorem as an axiom. So such "proofs" are useless because they don't tell us anything we didn't already know: in order to know that this is a valid proof we already have to know that the theorem is true.)

Computability is also crucial to the proof of the incompleteness theorem, because it is what allows the theory to talk about provability from itself (by talking about the program which prints a list of all its theorems). It is shockingly common to see people informally state the incompleteness theorem in a way which completely drops this computability requirement, but it is actually the heart of the whole thing. (The theory also needs to be capable of talking about enough arithmetic to talk about programs; as Chris Eagle says in the comments there are weak theories which don't have this property and so which also don't fall under the umbrella of the incompleteness theorem.)

Anyway, there are various ways to keep adding statements to a theory while keeping it consistent. If you believe that [Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) is consistent, for example, you can add to it the statement $\text{Con}(PA)$, obtaining a new theory $PA + \text{Con}(PA)$ which, by the incompleteness theorem, is strictly stronger than $PA$ itself, but which you ought to still believe to be consistent. Then you can keep going and add $\text{Con}(PA + \text{Con}(PA))$, and so forth. It is even possible to iterate this construction transfinitely although things get delicate up there. I haven't read it but I'm told the book to read here is Torkel Franzen's *[Inexhaustibility](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1568811756)*.

Comment: It's perhaps worth noting that the Incompleteness Theorem also has a requirement about the theory being able to interpret enough of arithmetic.  The theory of algebraically closed fields of a fixed characteristic is complete, consistent, and computable, and yet also isn't a counterexample to the Incompleteness Theorem.